# Convert this for loop to an apply function R

Tags: r, for-loop, mapply

I have a vector of data such as the following:

```
data <- c(1, 3, 4, 7)
```

And I would like to apply a function to every pair of elements in the vector such that it will return an upper triangle matrix as the following does:

```
mat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(data), ncol = length(data))
for (i in 1:(length(data) - 1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):length(data)) {
    mat[i, j] <- "-"(data[j], data[i])
  }
}
```

But I would like to do so with an apply type function instead of a for loop.

I am unsure how to do so. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `combn`

```
mat[lower.tri(mat, diag=FALSE)] <- combn(data, 2,
                            FUN= function(x) x[2]-x[1])
t(mat)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA    2    3    6
#[2,]   NA   NA    1    4
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA    3
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(data), ncol = length(data))
```

Comment: @nicola Thanks for the comments.  Looks like it is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Using `outer`:

```
t(outer(data,data,"-"))*
    NA^lower.tri(matrix(0,length(data),length(data)),diag=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA    2    3    6
#[2,]   NA   NA    1    4
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA    3
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```